# Match word irrespective of the case

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, case-insensitive

Dataset:

```
> df
Id       Clean_Data
1918916  Luxury Apartments consisting 11 towers Well equipped gymnasium Swimming Pool Toddler Pool Health Club Steam Room Sauna Jacuzzi Pool Table Chess Billiards room Carom Table Tennis indoor games 
1495638  near medavakkam junction calm area near global hospital
1050651  No Pre Emi No Booking Amount No Floor Rise Charges No Processing Fee HLPROJECT HIGHLIGHTS
```

Below is the code which is successfully returning the matching words in **ngrams** from the list of values in **Category.py**

```
df['one_word_tokenized_text'] =df["Clean_Data"].str.split()
df['bigram'] = df['Clean_Data'].apply(lambda row: list(ngrams(word_tokenize(row), 2)))
df['trigram'] = df['Clean_Data'].apply(lambda row: list(ngrams(word_tokenize(row), 3)))
df['four_words'] = df['Clean_Data'].apply(lambda row: list(ngrams(word_tokenize(row), 4)))
token=pd.Series(df["one_word_tokenized_text"])
Lid=pd.Series(df["Id"])
matches= token.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).str.extractall("|".join(["({})".format(cat) for cat in Categories.HealthCare])))
match_list= [[m for m in match.values.ravel() if isinstance(m, str)] for match in matches]
match_df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":Lid,"jc1":match_list})


def match_word(feature, row):
    categories = []

    for bigram in row.bigram:
        joined = ' '.join(bigram)
        if joined in feature:
            categories.append(joined)
    for trigram in row.trigram:
        joined = ' '.join(trigram)
        if joined in feature:
            categories.append(joined)
    for fourwords in row.four_words:
        joined = ' '.join(fourwords)
        if joined in feature:
            categories.append(joined)
    return categories

match_df['Health1'] = df.apply(partial(match_word, HealthCare), axis=1)
match_df['HealthCare'] = match_df[match_df.columns[[1,2]]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1)
```

**Category.py**

```
 category = [('steam room','IN','HealthCare'),
        ('sauna','IN','HealthCare'),
        ('Jacuzzi','IN','HealthCare'),
        ('Aerobics','IN','HealthCare'),
        ('yoga room','IN','HealthCare'),]
    HealthCare= [e1 for (e1, rel, e2) in category if e2=='HealthCare']
```

**Output:**

```
ID  HealthCare
1918916 Jacuzzi
1495638 
1050651 Aerobics, Jacuzzi, yoga room
```

Here if I mention the features in "Category list" in the exact **letter case** as mentioned in the dataset, then the code identifies it and returns the value, else it won't.
So I want my code to be case insensitive and even track "Steam Room","Sauna" under health category. I tried with ".lower()" function, but am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit 2: only category.py is updated

## Category.py

```
category = [('steam room','IN','HealthCare'),
        ('sauna','IN','HealthCare'),
        ('jacuzzi','IN','HealthCare'),
        ('aerobics','IN','HealthCare'),
        ('Yoga room','IN','HealthCare'),
        ('booking','IN','HealthCare'),        
        ]
category1 = [value[0].capitalize() for index, value in enumerate(category)]
category2 = [value[0].lower() for index, value in enumerate(category)]

test = []
test2 =[]

for index, value in enumerate(category1):
    test.append((value, category[index][1],category[index][2])) 

for index, value in enumerate(category2):
    test2.append((value, category[index][1],category[index][2]))

category = category + test + test2


HealthCare = [e1 for (e1, rel, e2) in category if e2=='HealthCare']
```

## Your unaltered dataset

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk import ngrams, word_tokenize
import Categories
from Categories import *
from functools import partial


data = {'Clean_Data':['Luxury Apartments consisting 11 towers Well equipped gymnasium Swimming Pool Toddler Pool Health Club Steam Room Sauna Jacuzzi Pool Table Chess Billiards room Carom Table Tennis indoor games',
                     'near medavakkam junction calm area near global hospital',
                     'No Pre Emi No Booking Amount No Floor Rise Charges No Processing Fee HLPROJECT HIGHLIGHTS '],
'Id' : [1918916, 1495638,1050651]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df['one_word_tokenized_text'] =df["Clean_Data"].str.split()
df['bigram'] = df['Clean_Data'].apply(lambda row: list(ngrams(word_tokenize(row), 2)))
df['trigram'] = df['Clean_Data']).apply(lambda row: list(ngrams(word_tokenize(row), 3)))
df['four_words'] = df['Clean_Data'].apply(lambda row: list(ngrams(word_tokenize(row), 4)))
token=pd.Series(df["one_word_tokenized_text"])
Lid=pd.Series(df["Id"])
matches= token.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).str.extractall("|".join(["({})".format(cat) for cat in Categories.HealthCare])))
match_list= [[m for m in match.values.ravel() if isinstance(m, str)] for match in matches]
match_df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":Lid,"jc1":match_list})


def match_word(feature, row):
    categories = []

    for bigram in row.bigram:
        joined = ' '.join(bigram)
        if joined in feature:
            categories.append(joined)
    for trigram in row.trigram:
        joined = ' '.join(trigram)
        if joined in feature:
            categories.append(joined)
    for fourwords in row.four_words:
        joined = ' '.join(fourwords)
        if joined in feature:
            categories.append(joined)
    return categories

match_df['Health1'] = df.apply(partial(match_word, HealthCare), axis=1)
match_df['HealthCare'] = match_df[match_df.columns[[1,2]]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1)enize(row), 4)))
```

## Output

```
print match_df 

+--------+----------------+-------------+------------------------------------+
|ID      |jc1             |Health1      |HealthCare                          |
+--------+----------------+-------------+------------------------------------+
|1918916 |[sauna, jacuzzi]|             |['sauna', 'jacuzzi'],['steam room'] |
+--------+----------------+-------------+------------------------------------+
|1495638 |                |             |                                    |
+--------+----------------+-------------+------------------------------------+
|1050651 |    [Booking]   |             |  ['Booking'],[]                    |                |
+--------+----------------+-------------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: No i am not supposed to modify my dataset values. I just want to match the words with the category values irrespective of the case.

Comment: well you are already adding columns to your dataset, I have just edited my answer from the way I see it you can either :

- a) make everything lower/upper for the 3 columns your are creating and test only with lower/upper case variables
- b) try to reproduce (using python code) every possible capitalisation formats in your Category.py 

the latter seems to be overkill.

Comment: Sorry if my question is confusing, I understand your point, but my concern is , my final output value case should not differ from what i have recieved in the dataset. If "Sauna","Steam Room" have InitialCaps, then the same must be presented in output. I just mean that, if my dataset contains similar words in future with lower or upper case, then my code must be case insensitive to detect it. :)